# FileNotFoundError writing to Azure DFS in Python

Tags: python, azure

When using this code

```
with open('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/jenks_tweets.txt', 'w') as f:
   for item in final_tweets:
     f.write('%s\n' % item)
```

I get this error:

### FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/jenks_tweets.txt'

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
16
17
---> 18 with open('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/jenks_tweets.txt', 'w') as f:
19    for item in final_tweets:
20      f.write('%s\n' % item)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/jenks_tweets.txt'

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the slashes were facing in the wrong direction

```
with open('\dbfs\FileStore\tables\jenks_tweets.txt', 'w') as f:
   for item in final_tweets:
     f.write('%s\n' % item)
```